# How to dynamically slice array without eval?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am in a situation where I need to dynamically slice an array of variable shape/ dimension. So I assemble a string to access it.

This works fine when **accessing** the data.

```py
some_data = eval("arr[:,[ci]]")

#or

some_data = eval("arr[:,[ci],:]")

#or

some_data = eval("arr[:,:,:,[ci]]")

#etc.
```

But the limitations of `eval()` prevent me from **assigning** using this approach.

```py
eval("arr[:,[ci]]") = some_data
```

Is there a way I can slice without `eval()`?

Comment: using a few tags since slicing is not unique to numpy

Comment: "where I need to dynamically slice an array of variable shape/ dimension" *What do you mean by "dynamically"*? what kind of input do you receive, and what needs to happen as a result? Can you control the input format? What kinds of operations need to be supported / specified by that data?

Comment: "using a few tags since slicing is not unique to numpy" You should use tags according to *the thing that you want to slice*. `python` and `numpy` make sense here, assuming that you're talking about a Numpy ndarray (which makes sense for the syntax you show); `pytorch` is *only* a relevant tag if someone else *must* use `pytorch` in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: well i am working with both numpy and torch data interchangeably here, and i am open to using all 3 methods to solve it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It receives data of various shape/ dimensions where one dimension will need to be permuted then replaced

Comment: Okay, so... accept as input a tuple of indices, and use that to slice? Slice indices like `:` are represented by the built-in `slice` type.

Comment: Or if you're only slicing one dimension at a time, you can accept the `ci` value and a number indicating the dimension, and construct that tuple.

Comment: very cool! i did not know about `slice()` thank you

Comment: I can think of no situation where your solution with eval would be reasonable and the best piece of advice I can give you is to forget that `eval` even exists. It's not doing you any favors.

Comment: I added a detailed answer, because there are a couple of useful techniques here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the indexing operation for a type is implemented by the [`__getitem__`/`__setitem__`/`__delitem__` magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). To understand how indexing syntax is interpreted, and thus how these methods are called, we can simply define our own class:

```
class test:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return idx

test()[:, [1,2,3], ...]
# result: (slice(None, None, None), [1, 2, 3], Ellipsis)
```

This `slice` type is a built-in type mentioned earlier in the same documentation, with a link to [more specific information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).

`Ellipsis` is simply the name of the object created by the literal syntax `...`. It's what Numpy uses to represent the complete extent of any number of axes - so this lets us avoid worrying about the dimensionality of the array we're working with.

The important thing to realize is that *we can use that same index tuple directly, to get the same result.*

Thus, given a dimension along which to slice with `[ci]`, we can construct the necessary tuple, and index with it:

```
all = slice(None)
def make_index(ci, dimension):
    return (all,) * dimension + ([ci], Ellipsis)

# Now we can do things like:
arr[make_index(ci, dimension)] = some_data
```

Comment: Thank you! To characterize the use case; I was using `ci` to represent the column index when iterating over each column during permutation. The dimension of interest changes if the user has reshaped the data (unfortunately different algorithms require reordering dimensions).